# Is it possible to change the properties of a Microsoft Dynamics NAV page using c#?

Tags: c#, microsoft-dynamics, navision

Is it possible to change the properties of a Microsoft Dynamics NAV page using c#?

I am testing Dynamics Nav using C# and one problem that I ran into was that some properties of Nav pages need to be changed ( for example make a field on page visible or editable) in order for my tests to run. I have about 10 objects (pages) that I have to do this manually before I run my tests. So I was hoping to automate the process.

Comment: Not sure which testing approach you are referring to. Could you post some code maybe?

Answer (score 0):

The answer probably going to be - no. At least because it is against methodology. If you’re testing a page (simulating user actions) and the field is not visible/editable then it prevents test case from being successful. If the field is conditionally editable then you need to fulfill the conditions first.

Another situation is when field is accessible but hidden from page via customization. Then you need to add it to page manually. But this is required only once (per database).

Comment: The field is hidden from the page via customization. I tried using a web service to change personalization of a web client user in order to view the field but that did not work.

Comment: The field is hidden from the page via customization. I tried using a web service to change personalization of a web client user in order to view the field but that did not work. Every time I get a new build, the page objects are overwritten and so I manually update them in order for the regression tests to pass. Some databases have the fields made visible by default  but my test db does not. Yet I still need to test that the functionality for those fields did not break.

Comment: Can you use user profile with personalization for your test user?

Comment: I will try your suggestion. In the past, I believe it didn’t work because the user who logged in was the default windows user and not the test user. But I recently corrected that so that the test user logs into the web client and now I think the web service might work.